# How can I save two different information in my controller affecting one table in my DB

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

i don't know how to save different values in my db at the same time. i have this in my view

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('SoyaPrecioInternacional');?>
    <fieldset> 

        <?php 
        echo $this->Form->input('pais', array(
            'options' => array( 
            'CHICAGO' => 'Chicago', 
            'ROSARIO' => 'Rosario'
                ),'label'=>'Ciudad'
        ));
        echo $this->Form->input('precio', array('label' => 'Ingrese en Dolares $us','style'=>'width:500px; height:30px;'));
                echo $this->Form->input('pais', array(
            'options' => array( 
            'CHICAGO' => 'Chicago', 
            'ROSARIO' => 'Rosario'
                ),'label'=>'Ciudad'
        ));
        echo $this->Form->input('precio', array('label' => 'Ingrese en Dolares $us','style'=>'width:500px; height:30px;'));
        echo $this->Form->submit('Agregar Cambio', array('class' => 'form-submit',  'title' => 'Presione aqui para agregar datos')); 
    ?>
</fieldset>
```

and this in my controller

```
public function add()
    {
        $this->loadModel('SoyaPrecioInternacional');
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->request->data['SoyaPrecioInternacional']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
            if ($this->SoyaPrecioInternacional->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('La Información fue Guardada.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
        }
    }
```

but when i put a price for option 1 and another for option 2 in my controller only get the last choice form example
if i put a price for chicago the first option and then rosario the secon option in my db only appears the rosario value

Comment: Besides the obvious problems with your code, I think for receiving better answers it would be helpful if you'd explain your DB schema, ie how and why you are going to store multiple values for single columns (if that is actually what the code implies).

Comment: If you have two table I think you have two model,am I right ? If you have two table it is possible.At first ensure me that you have made two model.

Comment: thanks @ndm...my client whant like this...i think he is so lazy!!he want to save the price for chicago and rosario for once and that's my problem i don't know how to save two forms for one model...and about my DB schema  i have onlu id, precio, pais, fecharegistro. it works when the client save one price...please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('SoyaPrecioInternacional');?>
    <fieldset> 
        <?php 
        echo $this->Form->input('SoyaPrecioInternacional.1.precio', array('label' => 'Ingrese en Dolares $us','style'=>'width:500px; height:30px;'));
        echo $this->Form->input('SoyaPrecioInternacional.1.pais', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value'=>'ROSARIO'));
            ?>

            <?php 
            echo $this->Form->input('SoyaPrecioInternacional.2.precio', array('label' => 'Ingrese en Dolares $us','style'=>'width:500px; height:30px;'));
            echo $this->Form->input('SoyaPrecioInternacional.2.pais', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value'=>'CHICAGO'));

        echo $this->Form->submit('Agregar Cambio', array('class' => 'form-submit',  'title' => 'Presione aqui para agregar datos')); 
    ?>
```

and

```
public function add()
{
    $this->loadModel('SoyaPrecioInternacional');

        $this->request->data['SoyaPrecioInternacional']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $count=0;
        foreach($this->request->data['SoyaPrecioInternacional'] as $precios){
            $count++;
            $this->SoyaPrecioInternacional->create();
            $this->request->data['SoyaPrecioInternacional']['precio']=$precios['precio'];
            $this->request->data['SoyaPrecioInternacional']['pais']=$precios['pais'];

            $this->SoyaPrecioInternacional->save($this->request->data);
        }
    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }       

}
```